# Fourier series for a function with a "jump point".

Tags: fourier-series

Find the Fourier' series of $f(t)$, which:
$$
f(t)=
\begin{cases} 
\pi^2-t^2 & \text{if} &  t\neq 1/\pi^n & n\in \mathbb{N} \\
t^2 &\text{if} &  t= 1/\pi^n & n\in \mathbb{N} 
\end{cases}
$$
I tried to make a continuous piecewise function which links the points $t=1/\pi^n\pm \epsilon$ with $t=1/\pi^n$, where $\epsilon$ tends to zero, but the fourier coefficients are kind of large.

I have not found any example of a Fourier' series like this one, so an example would be appreciated.